# Any good way to programmatically change nginx config file from python?

Tags: python, nginx

I have a python script that dynamically alters nginx config file (`nginx.conf`). Since nginx configuration is not in `ini` format, i currently use some regexp to parse and modify file content. Is it the only way or some better way to programmatically alter nginx configuration exist?

Comment: Why not use a template to generate the file?

Comment: @Mart I don't generate it - i alter existing one. Script is used on existing servers that already has nginx up and running with existing config files. I add or remove items depending on some logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found out about [python-nginx](https://github.com/peakwinter/python-nginx), which works great out-of-the-box using only Python, and doesn't seem to need any C or required Python package at all! Could improve docs a bit. Maybe I'll send a pull request for that.

Answer (score 11):

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/nginx-conf
2. You might use the **PyNginxConfig Parser**.
   http://code.google.com/p/pynginxconfig/source/browse/pynginxconfig.py#208
   This implementation is close to the original one.
3. There is also [ServerMgr](http://pythonhosted.org/servermgr/nginx.html).
   It's not really a parser, just allows for basic mappings.
4. Last but not least, actually first, because based on pyparsing:
   https://github.com/pyhedgehog/nginxparser

   `pip install git+https://github.com/pyhedgehog/nginxparser.git`

Comment: Install [nginxparser](https://github.com/fatiherikli/nginxparser) with `pip install git+https://github.com/fatiherikli/nginxparser.git
`

Comment: The https://gihub.com/fatiherikli/ account appears to have changed or closed. While unsure what would be the best fork to suggest, this one at least has a Credits section stating it was forked from the original repository: https://github.com/pyhedgehog/nginxparser

Answer (score 11):

NGINX Inc started providing a library in 2017 that is a "quick and reliable way to convert NGINX configurations into JSON and back." It's called [crossplan](https://github.com/nginxinc/crossplane) and you can get it with `pip`.

```
pip install crossplane
```

With this you can parse a file to JSON, deserialize, manipulate, serialize back to JSON, and then convert back to the NGINX config file format.

Answer (score 4):

There seems to exist an [augeas lens](http://augeas.net/docs/references/lenses/files/nginx-aug.html) supporting at least a subset of the nginx config file syntax. Augeas also has [Python bindings](http://augeas.net/download.html).

Comment: Looks kinda overkill to use library written in C with python bindings for simple text file processing O_O.

Comment: For anyone looking to parse nginx.conf files from languages other than Python Augeas also has [bindings for a number of other langauges](http://augeas.net/download.html), in addition to a shell tool. Also my 2 cents - Augeas is the most robust solution as it provides a common API to parse many .conf files from different languages. The nginx lens is currently restricted to a subset of nginx configuration syntax but it's fairly straightforward to extend.

Answer (score -2):

There is now [nginx-conf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nginx-conf), an NPM module that provides programmatic access to nginx configurations.

Comment: The OP asked about Python -- why is the accepted answer one suggesting an NPM (Javascript) module?

Comment: Answer provides for JavaScript, not Python as the author requested.  Downvoted.